# reactjs how to style with an object instead of using in-line styling?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, babeljs

Here is my code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1 style = {{color:"red"}}>Foo</h1>,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

How come this works ^ but this doesn't:

```
var styles = {
    color:"red"
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1 style = {{styles}}>Foo</h1>,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

I want to style easily without having to type each style out every time i create a new DOM element...

Comment: if the answer worked, would you mind selecting it as the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single brackets in your render. Like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1 style = {styles}>Foo</h1>,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

The reason `style={{ styles }}` doesn't work is because it's the same as `style={{ styles: styles }}`, which passes along an object with a `styles` property, instead of the actual styles you defined for it.

Comment: O ok I didn't know it just returned the object. Thanks a lot man!